# How to Select Multiple values from a Multiple select List Box in Coded UI Test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am having a case where you can select multiple values from a list box so, how can you select those values in coded UI test by adding the object. You can do this by recording

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your multiselect listbox control is `MyListBox`, which you have already capture or searched.

**Multiselect HTML**

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="item1">Apple</option>
  <option value="item2">Orange</option>
  <option value="item3">Banana</option>
  <option value="item4">Grapes</option>
</select>
```

**This is how you select multiple item:**

```
var items = new string[] { "item1", "item4" }
MyListBox.SelectedItems = items;
```

or

```
var items = new int[] { 0, 3 }
MyListBox.SelectedIndices= items;
```